# Oracle Forms-Error 103 at line 11 column 2- Encountered the symbol USER_PASSWORD where expecting

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

```
declare

    v varchar2(3);
begin 
    select 'x'
    into v
    from user_details
    where
    USER_NAME = login.USER_NAME;
'and'
    USER_PASSWORD = login.USER_PASSWORD;

    if sql%found then
        open_form('D:\CREDEN SOFT\MENU\MAIN.FMX');

    end if;
    exception

    when no_data_found then 
    message('invalid user name or password....!');
    end;
```

Comment: Any one Please help me on that error....

Comment: remove the semicolon after `login.USER_NAME` and  quotes `''`  enclosing `and`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code that I modefied (though not tested) , please note that you have to add a column instead of x ( and make sure the length of the variable is correct 3 might be small)

```
declare    
    v varchar2(3);
begin 
    select 'x'
    into v
    from user_details
    where
    USER_NAME = login.USER_NAME
    and
    USER_PASSWORD = login.USER_PASSWORD;

    if v is not null then
        open_form('D:\CREDEN SOFT\MENU\MAIN.FMX');

    end if;

    exception
    when no_data_found 
    then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('invalid user name or password....');

    end;
```